# Fixed order query

Tags: craft3, sorting

Experiencing a weird issue trying to do a fixed order display of entries.
I have a bunch (array) of ids for entries I want to show as fixed order then want to append the remainder of relevant entries after (eg if related to a certain category).

If I do this works a charm:

```
{% set elements = craft.entries() %}
{% set elements = elements.relatedTo( element ) %}
{% set elements = elements.id( ids ).fixedOrder( true ) %}
```

But then if i do this to append to the ids array with the remaining entries it resorts to the default sorting order:

```
{% set elements = craft.entries() %}
{% set elements = elements.relatedTo( element ) %}
{% for item in elements if item.id not in ids %}
    {% set ids = ids|merge([item.id]) %}
{% endfor %} 
{% set elements = elements.id( ids ).fixedOrder( true ) %}
```

Any thoughts on why or how best to achieve this (eg return those that are set in order then append remainder)? Anything I am obviously missing in the above example?